# Image Converted to Byte not shown when Converting back to Image

Tags: android, image

In my android  application , i want to convert image into bytes and encode it. and send to database. But when i convert it back on image, it do not show. Please help.and tell me where i am making mistake

```
final Bitmap image=(images.get(position));



                int size = image.getRowBytes() * image.getHeight();



                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size); //Create a new buffer
                image.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

                byte[] array = buffer.array();

                 encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now on the server side when i decode this encoded imageString and write it, it do not display image.

```
                           Byte[] imageByteArary= base64.decode(encodedImageString);
                           File myfile=new File("D://test1.jpg");
            myfile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut=new FileOutputStream (myfile); 
            fOut.write(imageByteArray);
            fOut.close();
```

Comment: `copyPixelsToBuffer()` does not create a JPEG format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem.The String that you send from client side is not same what you receive at server side.

[Check this for solution](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html)

Comment: i am not finding solution. please please help

Comment: Best way capture the string before sending to server and capture the string received at server and then compare both. You will find your solution. In my case if we have enter so String was coming to next line but when it is sent to server it was added by "\n". Check the difference between both String which i said you and let me know the difference

Comment: Capture the encoded String at client side and http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html decode here and same do with server side string.